# neography / neo4j change relationship end point to another node

Tags: neo4j, neography

i am using neography as wrapper of the REST api for Neo4j graph database.
I often need to change the end node of a relationship, but i am not able to do this using neography.

Of course, i can delete the relation then recreate it with the new end point node, but it's not optimized.

Does anyone had this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j does not allow replacing the nodes of a relationship (see [javadoc](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8.1/org/neo4j/graphdb/Relationship.html)). So you only can create a new relationship to the new end node and delete the other relationship.