# neo4j change relationship target from one node to another

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Assume I have this model in neo4j:

```
          (n2) -> (n3)-> (n9)
           /\
           |
   (n4)<-(n1)->(n5)->(n6)
    |            |
    \/           \/ 
    (n7)         (n8)
```

I need a cypher to change relationship between (n1) and (n2) to (n1) and (n6), like this:

```
                     (n2) -> (n3)-> (n9)
                      /\
                      |
   (n4)<-(n1)->(n5)->(n6)
    |            |
    \/           \/ 
    (n7)         (n8)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) installed, you can use a graph refactoring procedure to change the end point of a relationship. You'll need a match query to get the relationship, and the new start node, then use:

```
call apoc.refactor.from(rel, newStartNode)
```

Comment: apoc.refactor.to(rel, newEndNode) comes in handy as well.

Comment: Note that the proc does not modify the existing relationship, since that isn't possible. Instead this procedure is shorthand for creating a new relationship, copying over the properties, and deleting the old relationship.

Answer (score 9):

For those without APOC, Here is how to copy the relationship

```
MATCH (n1)-[r1:foo]->(n2),(n6)
WHERE n1.id = 1 AND n2.id = 2 and n6.id = 6
CREATE (n2)-[r2:foo]->(n6)
SET r2=r1
DELETE r1
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [a StackOverflow question about changing endpoints of a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228145/neography-neo4j-change-relationship-end-point-to-another-node), Neo4j has no method for changing the start or end nodes of a relationship - [see the Javadoc for Relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Relationship.html).

But you could do this with a Cypher query that copied the properties of the first relationship to a new relationship using [the properties() function](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-properties), and then deleted the first relationship.

However, the ID would change in the process, and [Cypher's SET clause](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/) doesn't appear to allow you to manually set the ID for something.